# A more pythonic way of iterating a list while excluding an element each iteration

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
items = ["one", "two", "three"]

for i in range(0, len(items)):
    for index, element in enumerate(items):
        if index != i:
            # do something with element
```

Basically I want to exclude every element once and iterate the rest. So for the list I have above, I'd like the following iterations:

1. "two", "three"
2. "one", "three"
3. "one", "two"

The code I've written now seems a little C++-ish, is there a better solution? (I do not want to hold all possible lists in a variable)

EDIT: I didn't state this but the lists size isn't necessarily 3. It can be of any size.

EDIT 2: It seems there's another misunderstanding: if I have a list of N, then I want N lists of size N-1, each missing an element from the original list.

EDIT 3: A list with 4 items, should give this result:

1. 1, 2, 3
2. 1, 3, 4
3. 1, 2, 4
4. 2, 3, 4

Comment: I predict you will get a dozen answers to this, `itertools` and generator comprehensions will be invoked, but in the end nothing better than your initial code will be proposed.

Comment: Nah, he could have used `xrange(len(items))`.

Comment: Nah, he's already using Python 3 :)

Comment: re your second edit: That's not what your original code gives, though.

Comment: please give an example of your expected result with an input list of length 4

Comment: @balpha: that's just ludicrous. His code doesn't *give* anything. He posted the desired output. Three elements, each containing `len(items)-1` elements from the original list.

Comment: I don't know why the confusion, I thought I was pretty clear. Anyhow added an example for a list with 4 elements.

Comment: Yeah, I got it now. See my second update.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Although upvoted like crazy, my first solution wasn't what the OP wanted, which is
N lists, each missing exactly one of the N original elements:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> L = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
>>> for R in combinations(L, len(L) - 1):
...     print " and ".join(R)
...
one and two and three
one and two and four
one and three and four
two and three and four
```

See the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/2042394/list) for the source of the discussion below.

Comment: But the list I had written was just an example. In practice it can be of size N.

Comment: This is much more explicit and clear than the initial code, so I think it qualifies as better? At the very least this is more pythonic.

Comment: actually no, I want to iterate all "combinations" of length `N-1`.

Comment: @roger: You still want all combinations of length 2

Comment: It really is. Fair enough, you get my sheepish +1.

Comment: Okay, I'm in an edit war with myself right now -- sitting back to think for a moment.

Comment: Corrected now. It's permutations, not combinations.

Comment: please read my edit, I still think you got it backwards. Shouldn't `combinations(L, len(L) - 1)` do it?

Comment: I accepted your answer although @SilentGhost had the right solution before (maybe inspired by yours). But since you corrected it and your answer has more upvotes it seems more appropriate. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
[items[:i]+items[i+1:] for i in range(len(items))]
```

in py2.x use `xrange`. obviously, slicing all the time on a big sequence is not very efficient, but it's fine for short ones. Better option would be using [`itertools.combinations`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
>>> for a in itertools.combinations(items, len(items)-1):
    print(a)

('one', 'two')
('one', 'three')
('two', 'three')
```

Answer (score 1):

As roger predicted, an answer which doesn't really improve the existing code :)

```
a = ["one", "two", "three"]
for i in range(0, len(a)):
  print [val[1] for val in enumerate(a) if val[0] != i]
```